# how to float hint right?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to achieve a certain "look" in Android that was easy in swift on iOS.

This is my code so far:

```
  <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
            android:textColorHint="@color/niceblue"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextLabel">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:background="@drawable/textlines_hint"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:hint="Login Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This however produces this effect which is bad because the hint and the label overlap..

[image]

What I am going for is the ios variant look..

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how we can right align the hint (and optionally the text) but it can't be rtl because it is still "roman" alphabet, I just require it to hint right align and text right align including the hint

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to have a single hint or placeholder for `TextInputEditText` which should be part of `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout` parent will use the hint from child view.

But as you need different hint & placeholder for both `EditText` & `TextInputLayout`. You can try to use illusion in `EditText` with transparent text colour till it's not focused.

Your original Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        ....//Should be same as your xml properties
         >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            ...//Should be same as your xml properties
            android:textColorHint="@drawable/hint_selector"
            ...
         />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Color Selector - EditText Hint - hint_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="?android:textColorHint" />
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The above selector will make hint color in `EditText` as transparent till that view is not focused which will not overlap your `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: thanks, but that is not quite right.. I had already considered suppression, but the thing is (for me) a hint and a label are **not** the same and should be able to co-exist.. I think right-align would do it to be honest. I really like the label pop out effect in Android.. it's just a shame I can't seem to do the hint in a way that doesn't interfere

Comment: @MrHeelis Yes, it's a hack way to achieve this. That's the reason I have mentioned it's always better to have only one placeholder for `EditText` which will be used in TextInputLayout if user focuses on EditText.

Comment: @MrHeelis - Yes, I do understand your concern and eager to learn as well as how to do it. But the way `TextInputLayout` is implemented in android it should have only one placeholder for `EditText` which is very good in terms of UX. Why bother the user with a redundant placeholder. Please don't consider that I have a biased opinion on Mobile OS. They both are good in their own way. :)